# Is there a way to combine statements if & as in python?

Tags: python

I have been just wondering if it is possible to somehow combine 'if' and 'as' statements like this:

```py
if possible_error() as error:
  return error
```

instead of

```
error = possible_error()
if error:
  return error
```

where 'possible_error' function returns either empty string or error message. By doing so I could save one line of code.

I know that some compromise is to run this function twice:

```
if possible_error():
  return possible_error()
```

but I would rather avoid doing this.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the relatively new "walrus" operator is for:

```
if (error := possible_error()):
    return error
```

Comment: Wow, I did not even know that such operator exists. Thanks!

Comment: It was a somewhat controversial addition.  Minimizing the lines of code is not always a good target, because it tends to decrease readability.